# Making a Navigation bar to use across all pages

Tags: php, html, css, navbar

I am having issues getting my navigation bar to display across multiple pages.

I have already tried several methods including PHP and javascript but I can't get anything to work.

Here is my navbar code:

```html
<header>
   <ul class="navbar">
        <li style="left:5%; position:fixed;"><a href="index.html"><img width=35 height=35 src="images/4227LogoBig.png"></a></li>
        <li style="left: 14%; position:fixed;"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <!-- About us -->
            <div style="left: 27%; position:fixed;" class="dropdown">
                <a href="#">About Us</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <ul style="list-style: none;">
                        <li><a class="navbarLink" href="#">The Team</a></li>
                        <li><a class="navbarLink" href="#">Mentors</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- Robots -->
            <div style="left: 44%; position:fixed;" class="dropdown">
                <a href="#">Robots</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <ul style="list-style: none;">
                        <li><a class="navbarLink" href="#">2018-2019</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- Outreach -->
            <div style="left: 58%; position:fixed;" class="dropdown">
                <a href="#">Outreach</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <ul style="list-style: none;">
                        <li><a class="navbarLink" href="#">2018-2019</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </li>
        <li style="left: 74%; position:fixed;"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </header>
```

and I am currently trying to use `<?php include('includes/navbar.php');?>` in the body of my html.

I can't get any of it to display using this method however if I put it directly in the index.html it functions flawlessly. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance! Here's a link to the demo homepage if you're interested. http://chasekaplan.com/FTC%204227/index.html

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you're using PHP code in index.html and your web server is not configured to process .html files with PHP. View the page source in your browser and see if that `<?php include...` is there. If it is, you'll need to either change to index.php or update your server settings to process .html files with PHP.

Comment: Changing index.html to index.php did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Didn't realize you have found the answer. Well Done! I was too late to answer below.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Code runs only within the `.php` files. You can't include a `.php` file within a `.html` file.

Ensure that your main page is `.php`, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

A common reason for PHP `include`, `require`, `require_once` not displaying files is incorrect pathing. Pathing rules can vary between webservers. First thing to try is adding a leading slash to reference the root. Some servers will work only with it, some only without it.

Since `'includes/navbar.php'` isn't loading, try `'/includes/navbar.php'`.

Depending on how the server's configured and where your pages are relative to the root, you may need to explicitly reference the root path. For example, `include(__DIR__ . 'includes/navbar.php');` or `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'includes/navbar.php');` Note: you may need to add the leading slash like so `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/navbar.php');`